# Cis trans isomer and cyclic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry

8 Calcitriol is a steroid hormone found in human blood.

Calcitriol shows geometrical isomerism.
Give the number of geometrical isomers of calcitriol, including calcitriol.[image]
I’m confused I think it doesn’t have a single geometric isomer because rotation is restricted in cyclic compounds! What is the concept behind it!

Comment: The question is not asking about conformers. It's about geometrical isomers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for calcitriol:
[image]
Assuming only Z and E isomer 64 isomers are possible .For rest of isomers (3 ,ZZ,EZ,EE)
each will have 64 isomers.

For Z and E isomer 64 isomers are :

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbCtd.png)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Quoting 
MARCH’S ADVANCED ORGANIC CHEMISTRY REACTIONS, MECHANISMS,AND STRUCTURE SIXTH EDITION 
Michael B. Smith ,Jerry March
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you produce the structures for all 64 isomers?

Comment: @andselisk: If you consider all stereo centers, there should be $2^6 \times 4= 256$ different structures. Therefore, I gave only 4 ($EE, EZ, ZZ, ZE$) possible $E/Z$-isomers. I thought giving all 256 isomers would be too much for OP. However, Chakravarthy Kalyan did a great job arranging at least 64 of them. :-)

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne I see. Still 64 is an impressive number and I don't think it's been done manually in ChemDraw or something. There must be some way to do this programmatically. As the author remains silent, the tension raises:)

Comment: @andselisk i have used good ol paper an pencil with chemdraw to convert into reality.I got all 256 isomers but time constraints did not allow me.I will update.Thankyou.

Comment: @ChakravarthyKalyan Oh. So you've drawn 64 isomer structures in ChemDraw manually, and now you are about to add 192 structures on top of that. You left me speechless standing here applauding.

Answer (score 2):

The following diagram depicts the four possible geometrical isomers of calcitriol:

[image: Calcitriol Isomers]

Comment: This is more complex than simple *cis/trans*-isomerism. This is *E/Z*-isomerism. If you look at all four structures, no structural changes have been made. All about geometry of trisubstituted double bonds. You may read: https://www.chemguide.co.uk/basicorg/isomerism/ez.html.